# Cake PHP 2.10 limit paginated model records

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I'm working inside a Cake PHP 2.10 application and need to use the Cake paginator for my model to provide a paginated view for the end user.

The issue I'm facing is that I need to join other models to my `Application` model, such as an `ApplicationPayday`. Of which, there are millions of rows of each model.

The user in my system doesn't need to see the millions of paginated results, maybe only the last 1,000.

I've added a `limit` to my Paginator settings, but Cake is still getting all of my applications from my table, what am I missing?

```php
// define pagination settings
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'limit' => 50, // <-- doesn't seem to be limiting at all?
        'maxLimit' => 5,
        'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'tlp_application_paydays',
                        'alias' => 'ApplicationPayday',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'ApplicationPayday.application_id = Application.id'
                        )
                ),
                array(
                        'table' => 'tlp_application_types',
                        'alias' => 'ApplicationType',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                'ApplicationType.id = Application.application_type'
                        )
                )
        ),
        'order' => array(
                'Application.id' => 'desc'
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
);

// run query to get applications via paginated settings
$applications = $this->Paginator->paginate('Application');
```

I'm doing everything the [docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup) says to do, which is to just define `limit` in the paginator settings, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You actually want a limit on the join from the second table `ApplicationPayday`. You can't do this if you use joins. A `innerjoin` will select all matching data.

You should create a `hasMany` relationship between the two tables with `limit` like this. You can create it on the fly with `bindModel` like in the example below (if it's not already defined in the model class).

```
$this->Application->bindModel([
    'hasMany' => [
        'ApplicationPayday' => [
            'className' => 'ApplicationPayday',
            'foreignKey' => 'application_id',
            'limit'  => '5', // this one will work because CakePHP will make a separated query for each application_id, with limit
        ],
        ...
    ]
]);

$this->Application->contain([
    'ApplicationPayday',
    ...
]);
```

You can read more about Linking Models:

https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany

And the `containable` feature that helps you limit what your `find` method returns, without using `recursive`:

https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html